# ¿Cómo crear un login en Java?

Tags: java, login

Tengo un proyecto en donde tengo que crear un login en donde el usuario especifique cuántos usuarios se van a registrar, el nombre de cada usuario y la contraseña, los cuales se guardaran en dos arrays. Una vez generados los registros tengo que evaluar si el usuario y la contraseña coinciden con la del registro para dar acceso al resto del programa.

Ya tengo creado el registro de los usuarios pero no sé cómo hacer que identifique la contraseña de cada usuario para que al pedir el inicio de sesión la contraseña coincida con el usuario ingresado.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora y me surgió la duda al no poder iniciar sesión si se registran dos usuarios y el usuario desea iniciar la sesión del registro 2:

```
    public static void contra() {
    //Registro de usuarios
    int numUsers;
    int i;
    int passw[]= {000,000,000,000,000,};
    String users[]= {"Sin datos","Sin datos","Sin datos","Sin datos","Sin datos"};
    int tempP;//Contraseña temporal para evaluar con el array
    String tempU;//Usuario temporal para evaluar con el array
    int tries=1;//Contador de intentos

    System.out.println("Cuántos usuarios deseas registrar?");
    numUsers=s.nextInt();
    for(i=1;i<=numUsers;i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del usuario "+i);
        users[i]=s.next();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la contraseña del usuario "+users[i]);
        passw[i]=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Usuario registrado con éxito!");
    }
    //Autenticación de los usuarios
    do {
        for(i=1;i<=numUsers;i++){
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del usuario");
            tempU=s.next();
            if(tempU.equals(users[i])) {
                System.out.println("Ingresa la contraseña del usuario "+tempU);
                tempP=s.nextInt();
                if(tempP==passw[i]) { 
                    System.out.println("Acceso concedido!");
                    /*while(dec!=1||dec!=2) {
                        System.out.println("Cómo deseas ingresar los datos?\n 1)TECLADO\n 2)ARGUMENTOS");
                        dec=s.nextInt();
                        switch(dec) {
                        case 1:
                            KeyIn.main(null);
                            menu();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ArgIn.main(null);
                            menu();
                            break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Se esperaba una opción válida");
                                continue;

                        }
                        break;
                    }*/
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Contraseña incorrecta");
                    tries++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Usuario incorrecto");
                tries++;
                continue;
            }
    continue;
    }
break;
}while(tries<=5);//Después de 5 intentos el programa se detiene

}
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tenes un problema de logica. Al pedir los usuarios, para validar, debes recorrer todo el array de vuelta, y no buscarlos en el mismo orden ingresados.

Comment: ¿Recorrer el array?

Comment: Deberias leer sobre como se recorren los datos de un array en java (hay muchas formas de hacerlo, for...next seria la mas simple)

Comment: Ya te entendí, muchas gracias ya sé cómo hacerlo :D

Comment: Como principiante que soy.  Te recomiendo hacerlo con SQLite. Es mucho más sencillo.